# Name that Movie

Tags: rebus, knowledge, computer-puzzle

The following each describe a movie title. Figure out what they are! (I'm really bad at intros.)

1.

```
:*:*!!
```

2.

```
extern int bake(double pct);
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  return bake(0.5);
}
```

3.

```
  (traffic cop gets his license suspended for unpaid parking tickets)
- (pressing instrument)
+ (Hyperion)
```

Comment: Shouldn't #3 make more sense as (Hyperion) + (cop) - (instrument)

Comment: I suppose that would make an easier puzzle, yes.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Number 1 is

> Kiss Kiss Bang Bang

Number 2 is

> Half Baked

Number 3 is

> From Tim's answer, Ironic - Iron + Titan = Titanic

Comment: Number 3, something like: Irony - Iron + ?.

Comment: Haha!The irony of the titanic sinking because of an iceberg crash though it is made of iron.

Answer (score 8):

3.

> Ironic - Iron + Titan = Titanic

Comment: Well done! I was hoping the clue wasn't too obtuse. :)